# How to Create Relationships in Dataverse After Exporting Tables from MS Access

Tags: ms-access, dataverse

I have an MS Access database with a couple dozen tables in it.  In the MS Access database there are no configured constraints or relationships, but the data does support those relationships.  After I export the tables to Dataverse, I am unable to create a relationship to existing fields.

I can create a new relationship between the tables which will create a new column on the child table and if I enter data in that newly created child column, the relationship works fine - however, my data is in a different column in a different format (think an existing employee id).

How can I create a relationship in dataverse using existing columns created during an export from MS Access?

Thanks in advance for any tips!